# Method for all rows of a PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have troubles designing a working `udf` for my task on PySpark (python=2.7, pyspark=1.6)

I have a `data` DataFrame which looks like this :

```
+-----------------+
|         sequence|
+-----------------+
|         idea can|  
|        fuel turn|          
|      found today|  
|           a cell|         
|administration in|           
+-----------------+
```

And for each row in `data` I'd like to lookup info in an other DataFrame called `ggrams` (based on the attribute `sequence`), compute aggregates and return that as a new column in `data`.

My feeling is that I should do it that way :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def compute_aggregates(x):
    res = ggrams.filter((ggrams.ngram.startswith(x)) \
                              ).groupby("ngram").sum("match_count")
    return res.collect()[0]['sum(match_count)']

aggregate = udf(compute_aggregates, IntegerType())
result = data.withColumn('aggregate', compute_aggregates('sequence'))
```

But that returns a PicklingError.

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o1759.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
```

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. Python 2.7, pyspark 1.6 -- added to the post

Comment: you cannot use collect inside UDF. Can't you do that using `join` ?

Comment: Even removing `collect` keeps the same error. Unfortunately, I put the equal condition `ggrams.ngram == x` to keep it easier, but it could also be `ggrams.ngram.startswith(x)` or `ggrams.ngram.contains(x)` so it's not perfectly elligible for a join, unless I miss it. Let me modify my question to disambiguate

Comment: how big is your dataframe ? if not that big, consider doing a cross join then apply an udf to filter the lines.

Comment: non-equi-joins are not recommended

Comment: That `ggrams` dataframes are from Google N-grams and reach GBs when compressed as `.gz` -- maybe your suggestion still applies for that magnitude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown because you cannot access a different dataframe in the udf of another. The simplest way to fix this is by collecting the dataframe you want to check to.

The other option is a cross-join, but I can say from experience that collecting the other dataframe is faster. (I have no math/statistics to back this up though)

*so:*
  1. Collect dataframe you want to use in the udf
  2. Call to this collected dataframe (which is now a list) in your udf, you can/must now use python logic since you are talking to a list of objects

Note: Try to limit the dataframe that you are collecting to a minimum, select only the columns you need

**Update:**
If you are dealing with a very big set that would make collecting impossible, cross-join will most likely now work (it didn't for me at least). The problem is then that the **huge** cross product of the two dataframes will take so much time to create that the connection to the worker node will time-out, this causes an broadcast error. So see if there is any way that you can limit the columns that you are using, or if there is a possibility to filter out rows of which you can know for sure that they will not be used.

If all this fails, see if you can create some batch approach*, so run only the first X rows with collected data, if this is done, load the next X rows. This will most likely be terrible slow, but atleast it won't time-out (I think, I have not tried this personally since the collection was possible in my case)

*batch both, the dataframe you are running the udf on and the other dataframe, since you still cannot collect inside the udf, because you cannot acces the dataframe from there

Comment: apparently, the df are gbs ... you need a big computer then if you want to collect

Comment: hmm, thats bad, but there is no way to access one dataframe inside another one's udf. And cross-join will then mostlikely throw a broadcast exception since the worker-connection will time-out on such big sets (this happend to me)

Comment: I could still give it a try, this is done on a pretty large cluster